# ¿Cómo sumar datos obtenidos de API REST?

Tags: ruby

¿Cómo puedo sumar o restar datos obtenidos de esta API REST? He intentado lo siguiente:

```
require 'uri'
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

url = URI("https://api.bitfinex.com/v1/trades/IOTAUSD")

http = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
http.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
response = http.request(request)

contents = JSON.parse(response.read_body)
```

Al ejecutar `puts contents` me da el siguiente resultado:

```
{"timestamp"=>1508855093, "tid"=>81129849, "price"=>"0.472", "amount"=>"73.0176", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855093, "tid"=>81129848, "price"=>"0.47304", "amount"=>"26.9824", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855092, "tid"=>81129843, "price"=>"0.4739", "amount"=>"58.33952044", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855091, "tid"=>81129834, "price"=>"0.47391", "amount"=>"276.96204141", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855083, "tid"=>81129798, "price"=>"0.47381", "amount"=>"500.43231687", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855081, "tid"=>81129790, "price"=>"0.47391", "amount"=>"202.08822712", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855081, "tid"=>81129789, "price"=>"0.4739", "amount"=>"8.59332771", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855080, "tid"=>81129783, "price"=>"0.4704", "amount"=>"67.87943325", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855080, "tid"=>81129782, "price"=>"0.47072", "amount"=>"501.0", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855080, "tid"=>81129781, "price"=>"0.471", "amount"=>"391.12056675", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855079, "tid"=>81129779, "price"=>"0.471", "amount"=>"3952.74088094", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855079, "tid"=>81129778, "price"=>"0.47111", "amount"=>"1714.89631906", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855079, "tid"=>81129777, "price"=>"0.47304", "amount"=>"26.9824", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855076, "tid"=>81129761, "price"=>"0.47111", "amount"=>"239.3340074", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855076, "tid"=>81129760, "price"=>"0.47112", "amount"=>"1258.4688926", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855076, "tid"=>81129759, "price"=>"0.47304", "amount"=>"26.9824", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855076, "tid"=>81129758, "price"=>"0.47391", "amount"=>"5000.0", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855074, "tid"=>81129738, "price"=>"0.47391", "amount"=>"178.92906348", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855074, "tid"=>81129737, "price"=>"0.4739", "amount"=>"49.67083652", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"buy"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129715, "price"=>"0.471", "amount"=>"4556.13855231", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129714, "price"=>"0.471", "amount"=>"1.0", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129713, "price"=>"0.47101", "amount"=>"3.0", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129712, "price"=>"0.4711", "amount"=>"2000.0", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129711, "price"=>"0.47111", "amount"=>"19.23916668", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129710, "price"=>"0.472", "amount"=>"3788.05322293", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129709, "price"=>"0.47202", "amount"=>"18.04438332", "exchange"=>"bitfinex", "type"=>"sell"}
{"timestamp"=>1508855070, "tid"=>81129708, "price"=>"0.47204", "amount"=>"18.03899762", "exchange}
```

Lo que quiero hacer es sumar todas los `amount` de los `sell` y todos los `amount` de los `buy` aparte.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: debes ser mucho mas claro en lo que quieres.. que has probado, intentado, hecho hasta ahora?

Comment: @JeisonPerez es muy importante revises los enlaces que te proporciona gbianchi, veo que no has al menos realizado el [tour] , si deseas realizar pregutnas como estas vas a tener respuestas que no son de calidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `select` para obtener todos los registros de cada tipo (i.e. `sell`, `buy`), seguido de `map` para obtener los valores de `amount` y, finalmente sumarlos (con `reduce`); algo así:

```
total_sell = contents.select { |item| item["type"] == "sell" }
                     .map { |item| item["amount"].to_f }
                     .reduce(:+)
#=> 708877.0513117099


total_buy = contents.select { |item| item["type"] == "buy" }
                    .map { |item| item["amount"].to_f }
                    .reduce(:+)
#=> 321607.8393008502
```

---

**BONUS**: Dado que la lógica es la misma tanto para `total_sell` como para `total_buy` (solo cambia el valor de `type`), podrías generar un método (e.g. `total`) que encapsule esa lógica y llamarlo para cada total; por ejemplo:

```
def total(body, type)
  body.select { |i| i["type"] == type }.map { |i| i['amount'].to_f }.reduce(:+)
end

total_sell = total(contents, "sell")  #=> 708877.0513117099
total_buy  = total(contents, "buy")   #=> 321607.8393008502
```

O bien, también podrías optar por utilizar un *hash* para almacenar los totales en lugar de variables separadas; por ejemplo:

```
total = ["sell", "buy"].each_with_object({}) do |type, t|
  t[type] = contents.select { |i| i["type"] == type }.map { |i| i['amount'].to_f }.reduce(:+)
end
#=> {"sell"=>708877.0513117099, "buy"=>321607.8393008502}

total["sell"]  #=> 708877.0513117099
total["buy"]   #=> 321607.8393008502
```

Comment: Gracias.
ya te muestro si me funciono

Comment: @JeisonPerez Mira nuevamente mi respuesta, la he actualizado para incluir la suma de todos los `buy` y todos los `sell`.

Comment: @JeisonPerez Gracias por la observación, ya he cambiado el `to_i` por `to_f` para que ejecute el cálculo correcto.

Comment: ahora solo me queda hacer un request con los siguientes parametros, (es para aumentar el historico de los datos)  imestamp false [time]  Only show trades at or after this timestamp
limit_trades false [int] 50 Limit the number of trades returned. Must be >= 1